# Can't seem to change CSS for elements using JQuery / jQuery mobile on Tablet

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

When clicking a hyperlink I width to change the `left` or `scrollLeft()` value of a DIV on my page. All works well when testing on my laptop (Windows: Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE) but when transfering to the tablet (Xoom2) nothing works... for example, consider the following...

```
$('#clickme').live("tap", function(event){
    alert($("#entry_level_phones").scrollLeft()) // the alert outputs a value which is a number so the .scrollLeft() is captured
    $("#entry_level_phones").scrollLeft(500) // nothing happens? This is ignored?
});
```

In this example I can guarentee that `#clickme`, which is a href and `#entry_level_phones` which is a div exist.

If I try to use good old JavaScript to do the same thing... I get the same results

```
$('#clickme').live("tap", function(event){
    alert($("#entry_level_phones").scrollLeft()) // the alert outputs a value which is a number
    document.getElementById("entry_level_phones").style.left = 500 + "px" // nothing happends? This is ignored?
});
```

even if I try to change something trivial like the CSS of `$("#entry_level_phones")` nothing happens however I can raise alerts, confirms or use the window object. Can someone please explain why?

My project uses jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile. Do I need to refresh the page to change the css using `$.mobile.changePage`

Comment: is $("#entry_level_phones") visible? "will not work if the element it is being applied to is hidden." http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Answer (score 0):

One option I would try is to replace `live` with `on`. Explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
Also, since alert is a blocking call, try using console.log.